# Facebook redirect after log in when the users is not logged in on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, authentication

I'm having a small problem with a facebook log in app. When i use the facebook log in on my website is ok and after success log in it redirects back to the previous url but if the user is not logged in on facebook or if he is logged in as page manager which has to switch to his account at this time the redirect doesn't work. Below is my php code for the log in.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }

    if (!empty($user )) {
        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($user_profile['name']);
        $uid = $user_profile['id'];
        $middle_name = mysql_real_escape_string($user_profile['middle_name']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($user_profile['email']);
        $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($user_profile['first_name']);
        $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($user_profile['last_name']);
        $birthday = $user_profile['birthday'];
        $picture = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture?width=140&height=140";
        $user = new User();
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username,$middle_name,$email,$birthday,$first_name,$last_name,$picture,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret);
        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
            $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

            $_SESSION['middle_name'] = $userdata['middle_name'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
            $_SESSION['birthday'] = $userdata['birthday'];
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $userdata['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $userdata['last_name'];

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
            $_SESSION['lastpage'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['lastpage']);
        }
    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email',
    ));
    header('Location: ' . $login_url);
}
```

Hope that some one has a solution...